# Spark destroys Thunderbolt & HDMI ports (and more)

Tags: thunderbolt, hdmi

I was trying to connect two external monitors to my Macbook (model A1502, EMC 2835 - early 2015).

The first monitor I connected via HDMI cable to the HDMI port. It worked OK.

Then I switched on the second one and connected it via HDMI cable with a HDMI/miniDP adapter to one of the Thunderbolt ports of the macbook.

There was a massive spark + smoke when I tried to insert the miniDP end into the Thunderbolt port. The surge/fuse protection of that room blew. It seems a fuse blew out.

The Macbook itself was not plugged in - it ran on battery.

The two sources of electricity could have been only the two monitors as the first one was connected to the laptop and I was about to connect the second one. But I would have not expected that the laptop could somehow cause a fuse of these two electricity sources.

The Macbook re-started as result of the spark but everything seems OK - apart from the fact that it cannot export any video signal (the laptop screen itself works fine) - none of the ports (HDMI/Thunderbolt) seem to be able to send a signal.

The monitors seem damaged, too. The second one cannot receive any signal. You can switch it on but nothing happens. The first one can receive signal only through its VGA port - the HDMI port used during the accident seems dead.

Can anyone explain why this happened?

Comment: **Rule #1:** if something sparks, smokes & blows the mains fuse/RCD **do not** plug it back in again to see if it still works. Take it to a qualified repairer.

Comment: I’ve edited three side questions out, we strongly prefer one question per question. If you get a good answer what happened, a how to repair or how to prevent question as a follow on might work great. Sorry the Mac got smoked by electricity.